# MS Graph API: Change page size after expanding children using query params

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the MS Graph API to expand children for their name and downloadURL. This is working very well:
`/path/?$expand=children($select=name,content.downloadUrl)`

I want to increase the page size from the default 200 to 999 (or whatever max size it will allow). Reading the MS Graph docs, I learned that I can use `$top=(int)` to change the max page size.

I've tried this:

`/path/?$expand=children($top=999&$select=name,content.downloadUrl)`

And this:
`/path/?$expand=children($select=name,content.downloadUrl;top=999)`

But neither of these solutions work. I also tried replacing `top=999` with something smaller like `top=3`, but that doesn't work either and always returns 200 children. It's as if the "top" isn't even applied.

Any help for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the page size in `$expand`. Expand should be used for situations where you want a sample set of the underlying data rather than the complete data set. It's generally best to think of it as a quick way to get the first page of data.

More importantly, you really don't want a REST API to give you "whatever the max size". HTTP may be super flexible but it is not optimal for moving large payloads and, as a result, performance will be horrible.

For optimal performance, you should try to keep your page sizes around 100 records (smaller is better) and processing each page of data as you receive it.

Comment: Technically the page size should be supported in `$expand` (e.g. that would allow you to optimize by requesting fewer than the default) - it would look like `$expand=children($top=10;$select=name,etc)`. Unfortunately this does NOT currently work in OneDrive for Business, but it's definitely on our radar to fix.